# Why are the commented lines not working in place of the non commented lines in the for loop of the merge function of this mergesort program

Tags: c, sorting, malloc, mergesort

This is my merge sort code in c language.

As you can see the commented lines in the for loop of the merge function of the code are essentially the same as the non-commented lines which successfully accomplish the task of merging the two sub-arrays.

My question is - what is wrong with the commented lines?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void merge(int *ar,int p,int q,int r)
{
    int l=r-p+1,*sub1,*sub2,l1=q-p+1,l2=r-q,i,j,k;
    sub1=(int*)malloc(l1*sizeof(int));
    sub2=(int*)malloc(l2*sizeof(int));
    for(i=0;i<l1;i++)
        *(sub1+i)=*(ar+p+i);
    for(i=0;i<l2;i++)
        *(sub2+i)=*(ar+q+i+1);
    i=j=0;
    for(k=0;k<l;k++)
    {
        //if(j=l2||(i!=l1&&(*(sub1+i)<*(sub2+j))))
        //    *(ar+p+k)=*(sub1+i++);
        //else
        //    *(ar+p+k)=*(sub2+j++);
        if(i<l1&&j<l2)
        {
            if(sub1[i]<sub2[j])
             ar[p+k]=sub1[i++];
            else
             ar[p+k]=sub2[j++];
        }
        else if(j<l2)
           ar[p+k]=sub2[j++];
        else
           ar[p+k]=sub1[i++];
    }
}

void mergesort(int *ar,int p,int q)
{
    if(p<q)
    {
        int m=(p+q)/2;
        mergesort(ar,p,m);
        mergesort(ar,m+1,q);
        merge(ar,p,m,q);
        //for(int i=p;i<=q;i++)
        //    printf("%d\t",*(ar+i));
        printf("\n");
    }
}


void main()
{
    int n,i,*ar;
    printf("Enter size of array\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    ar=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    printf("Enter the elements of the array\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        scanf("%d",(ar+i));
    mergesort(ar,0,n-1);
    printf("Sorted array is:\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d ",*(ar+i));
}
```

Comment: What is your question? why there must be something wrong? Are you getting an error when uncommenting those lines? If so, can you post the compiling command, and the error?

Comment: They are not "essentially the same". The logic in the commented out `if` statement is different from what you've left uncommented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the commented out code, if j < l2, then it copies from sub1, even if i >= l1 or sub1[i] > sub2[j]. The code below will work, but it's 3 conditionals for every move.

```
    for(k=0;k<l;k++)
    {
        if (i < l1 && (j >= l2 || *(sub1+i)<*(sub2+j)))
            *(ar+p+k)=*(sub1+i++);
        else
            *(ar+p+k)=*(sub2+j++);
    }
```

Comment: thanks bro....it worked, though after some digging i found that my code was also correct and running and it was a stupid "j=l2" used in the if cndition that brought the code down....m sorry for the showcase of my naivety